# TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined after POST (MEAN)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send POST data from AngularJS to Express. What I am doing at the moment is trying to send some POST stuff via curl.

I already tried sending the data. It gets send, I get 200 as a response. But whenever I try to access the data via body-parser through req.body I will get a 500 and the error that I posted at the very bottom.

I did a lot of research on that matter (past 4-5 hours...) and I think I checked the following common issues:

- I use some sort of request parser: body-parser
- I put my app.use(...) with body-parser middleware before requiring for routes
- I explicitly tell what Content-Type the POST uses
- I tried both application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I surrender. StackOverflowers. Help me, please.

curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "gala", "email": "ga@ga.g", "password": "123"}' localhost:3000/users
```

express.js

```
// glowny plik przygotowujacy aplikacje express

// wczytanie zaleznosci
var express = require('express')
var stylus = require('stylus')
var parser = require('body-parser')
var morgan = require('morgan')
var compress = require('compression')
var methodOverride = require('method-override')

// przygotowanie aplikacji, obsluga middleware i na koncu zwrocenie obiektu aplikacji
module.exports = function() {
    var app = express()

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        app.use(morgan('dev'))
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        app.use(compress())
    }

    app.use(parser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    app.use(parser.json())

    app.use(methodOverride())

    // uzycie jade jako silnika szablonow dla html
    app.set('views', __dirroot + '/app/views')
    app.set('view engine', 'jade')

    require(__dirroot + '/app/routes/index.server.route.js')(app)
    require(__dirroot + '/app/routes/users.server.route.js')(app)

    // mozliwosci uzywania statycznych plikow z folderu /public
    app.use(express.static(__dirroot + '/public'))

    return app
}
```

users.server.route.js:

```
var users = require(__dirroot + '/app/controllers/users.server.controller.js')

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.route('/users').post(function() {
        users.create()
    })
}
```

users.server.controller.js:

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User')

exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body)
}
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
   at Object.exports.create (/home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/app/controllers/users.server.controller.js:4:20)
   at /home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/app/routes/users.server.route.js:5:15
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at next (/home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at /home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
   at Function.proto.process_params (/home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
   at next (/home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
   at methodOverride (/home/gala/Projekty/cantr-crafting/node_modules/method-override/index.js:77:5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use Node or Express much but shouldn't you at least pass `req` into `users.create()` from the route handler, ie

```
app.route('/users').post(function(req, res) {
    users.create(req, res)
})
```

or maybe even

```
app.route('/users').post(users.create);
```

Comment: Hm. *scratches his head* That sounds like a reasonable thing to do... I'll check that and post back in a second.

@edit: yes. It did help. Now I feel like the most retarded guy in the Internets. Looking for complex solutions when problem is so simple. :D

Answer (score 2):

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined after POST (MEAN)**
you will get this error when your localhost ip is changed or the requesting ip is not correct  as you mentioned in the post url.
I got the same error when I troubleshoot my ethernet. Then my Ip address was changed. So check your ip. It will work..

Answer (score 0):

This happen for me because I have added some testing script on the chrome console and it seems like there were interference. you clean your console manually or run your app in another instance f chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

//Post processing after taking data from user..
app.post("/",function(req,res,next){
    var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
    var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
    var result = num1+num2;
    res.send("The result is "+ result);
});


// To create a server...
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started..3000");
});
```

I hope this code works for you as well. You may take help from above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add

```
app.use(express.json());
```

in my index.ts